# Create a site from a saved template not available

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, site-template

The option for creating a site template isn't available for me.

[image]

So what I did is go to SharePoint Designer and in the "Site" tab under "Site Options", I set "SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled" to "true".
Then I navigated to "/_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx" directly to save my template and then downloaded it from the SiteCollectionGallery.

**Now I want to create a site using this template but my template isn't appearing int the template list.**

[image]

Note : When I go to Site Settings -> Site Administration -> Click Create in the Sites and Workspaces dialog, I see for a brief moment other templates before being redirected to the page without my template. I copied the link before being redirected and got this message :

> An error occurred while processing your request.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this a Modern Team or Communication site or site that has had Publishing enabled? These sites do not support templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Microsoft supported option, you can follow below article and use site definitions instead of site template.
"saving publishing enabled sites as a template is not supported and it does not work. You cannot use this option to create new sites. Instead you should create site definitions (..\web server extensions\12\template\SiteTemplates) and provision the new site based on such a site definition".

https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2007/09/19/save-site-as-template-option-and-the-publishing-feature/

## SharePointPublishingFeature

Answer (score 0):

You can only create site templates from classic sites or modern team sites not connected to a Group.

1.Disable publishing features.

2.Allow custom scripts.

More information:

https://sharepointmaven.com/2-reasons-why-you-cannot-save-site-as-template-in-sharepoint/

Comment: I already tried that. Publishing features are already disabled and I don't have access to the SharePoint Admin Center